# Qt moveToThread works only the first time

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I'm creating an application performing an infinity task, so I decided to manage it with a QThread. On specific condition, this thread should spawns a temporary therad in order to perform some computation. The problem is that this works only the first time, while the second time I get this error:

```
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0xd29078) is not the object's thread (0x6e000df0).
Cannot move to target thread (0x6e002c68)
```

In the main I initialized the class and moved it in a QThread.

```
AccelerometerBuffer accBuffer;
QThread *accelerometerThread = new QThread;
accelerometerThread->setObjectName("AccelerometerThread");
accelerometerThread->setParent(&accBuffer);
accBuffer.moveToThread(accelerometerThread);
QObject::connect(accelerometerThread,SIGNAL(started()),&accBuffer,SLOT(readAccelerationData()));
QObject::connect(accelerometerThread,SIGNAL(finished()),accelerometerThread,SLOT(deleteLater()));
accelerometerThread->start();
```

In readAccelerationData, after condition, I should call another SLOT (saveData()) in the AccelerometerBuffer class and so the temporary thread should be spawned by the accelerometerThread.

```
if(condition){
    QThread* thread = new QThread;
    QThread::currentThread()->moveToThread(thread);
    connect(thread,SIGNAL(started()),QThread::currentThread()->parent(),SLOT(saveData()));
    connect(thread,SIGNAL(finished()),thread,SLOT(deleteLater()));
    thread->start();
}
```

The first time that the condition occurs, everything works fine, saveData is correctly executed.
The following times, instead, I get the error and I don't understand the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can only `moveToThread` from the owning thread. As soon as your move to another thread, the same call will no longer be able to do anything.

From https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread

> Warning: This function is not thread-safe; the current thread must be same as the current thread affinity. In other words, this function can only "push" an object from the current thread to another thread, it cannot "pull" an object from any arbitrary thread to the current thread.

Comment: So, the second time the accelerometerThread "lives" in the context of the temporary thread and cannot perform another `moveToThread`, right?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean @Cristiano

Comment: After moving the accelerometerThread to the temporary thread and as you said, current thread must be same as the current thread affinity, but I changed it and so I get the error. This is my main doubt